# JavaScript and Google Chrome, Input Streams and Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, stream

So my title might not explain things all to well, so I'll explain better, I am working on this extension for chrome that grabs synonyms from a dat file I found on the web from someone at MIT. I've gotten most of my idea written in Java (my native language), here it is so you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Grabber {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL mit = new URL(
            "http://mit.edu/~mkgray/jik/sipbsrc/src/thesaurus/old-thesaurus/lib/thesaurus.dat");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            mit.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (inputLine.startsWith("spoken")) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] synonyms = inputLine.substring("spoken".length())
                    .split("  ");
            for (String toPrint : synonyms) {
                if (toPrint.length() > 0) {
                    list.add(toPrint.trim());
                }
            }
            for (String toPrint : list) {
                System.out.println(toPrint);
            }
        }
    }
    in.close();
    }
}
```

Now, with my 'Codecademy' knowledge of the language, I don't know about all the library's and such included in Chrome's JavaScript API. We're should I start looking to complete this task? Oh, I also need to figure out how to make array's in JavaScript, act like the collection I wrote above.

Comment: Codeacademy did teach how to make an array, you may need to catch up a little. Some hints: 1. grub file with `XHR`; 2. `String.split()`; 3. use `Object` as dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Use XMLHttpRequest to fetch resources from the Web
xhr.open("GET", // HTTP GET method
    "http://mit.edu/~mkgray/jik/sipbsrc/src/thesaurus/old-thesaurus/lib/thesaurus.dat", 
    true // asynchronous
);
xhr.onreadystatechange = (function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) // success
    {
        // data fetched in xhr.responseText, now parse it
        var inputLines = xhr.responseText.split(/\r|\n|\r\n/); //Split them into lines
        /* A quick and brief alternative to 
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (inputLine.startsWith("spoken")) {
                ...
            }
        } */
        inputLines.filter(function(inputLine)
        {
            // You can also use 
            // return inputLine.substr(0, 6) == "spoken";
            // if you are not familiar with regular expressions.
            return inputLine.match(/^spoken/);
        }).forEach(inputLine)
        {
            var list = [];
            var synonyms = inputLine.substring("spoken".length).split("  ");
            synonyms.fonEach(function(toPrint)
            {
                if(toPrint.length > 0)
                    list.push(toPrint.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
                    //toPrint.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') is similar to toPrint.trim() in Java
                    //list.push(...) is used to add a new element in the array list.
            });
            list.forEach(function(toPrint)
            {
                // Where do you want to put your output?
            });
        });
    }
});
xhr.send(); // Send the request and fetch the data.
```